# Getting values from Bind. One key returns "0"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

I want to make a few strings out of the Bind values. Easy enough except that one of them is messing with me. `_surveyID` = "0"

**SurveyController:**

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "SurveyID,SurveyName,SenderID,ConsultantID,ResponderID,Question1,Question2,Question3,Question4,Question5,SurveyTime")] Survey survey)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {     
                    string _surveyID = survey.SurveyID.ToString();
                    string _surveyName = survey.SurveyName;
                    string _surveyTime = survey.SurveyTime.ToString();

                    //ANOTHER ATTEMPT, SAME RESULT
                    //string _surveyID = db.Surveys
                    //.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SurveyID == survey.SurveyID)
                    //.SurveyID;

                }
```

`SurveyID` to database = 1002

`SurveyID` to my `_surveyID` = "0"

Notice that `_surveyName` and `_surveyTime` are both working fine.

The `survey` Bind values: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqnP3.png

Why is my SurveyID beeing set to 0 when I try to pull out the value?

**EDIT:** Is the ID value created when beeing put into database? Is my code too soon in the flow of code?

**EDIT2:** This is a bump1

Comment: Are you passing `SurveyID` to the view, and then it's being passed to your Create method when you submit?

Comment: Yes, this is the second Create method. The one who recieves the values from the View

Comment: The first Create method creates the Survey?

Comment: Yes the first one just Creates ViewBags from the Model. Wich then the View takes inputs to.

Comment: Maybe you're not populating the viewmodel with the the survey id after it's created?

Comment: That's a good question. It should be done automatically. But why not double check?

Comment: Can you post your code for the create survey method?

Comment: If `SurveyID` is `0` is because your posting back a value of `0` or you not posting back any value for `SurveyID`. You need to post the `GET` method and the view showing how you generate the control for the `SurveyID` property. And if your needing to create this ugly `[Bind]` attribute, your should be using a view model.